# Why calling a class that extends Activity does not work when called from one that extends Plugin?

Tags: java, android, phonegap-plugins

I have a java Class that extends **Plugin** (PhoneGap), but when inside this class, i call another class that extends **Activity**, it just doesn't work !. i mean, it seems like it doesn't get called. To confirm this, i have change my second class, this time, not extending from Activity and it works fine. i need teh second one to extends from Activity because i am using this two utilities (getFileStreamPath and openFileOutput) to create a file

File filepath = getFileStreamPath("filename.CPCL"); and openFileOutput
FileOutputStream os = this.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: sorry, didn;t finished my question . 
an if the class does not extends from Activity i got the netx error message : 

**The method getFileStreamPath(String) is undefined for the type ....**

any tips ? 

has anyone faced the same problem before ? i am using cordoba 2.1.0 
thanks

Comment: "i mean, it seems like it doesn't get called" How did you determine this? Can you show the code?

Comment: @Henry, do you now how to paste the codes here ?? sorry i am new at SO

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Henry, ok, you can check it here @ this post : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320478/why-my-method-is-not-initializing-correctly.  i realized that if my second class doesn't extend from Activity, it works fine (of course i just let a simple println to test it), await for your comments.

Comment: Why did you start a new question? It would have been better to add the additional information to your other question to keep everything in one place.

Comment: @Henry, well, this is a quite different question than the original one. in the previous post i asked if my initialization was ok. in this i expose directly the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an app with a class which extends a custom `Service` that calls another class which extends `Activity`.

First I instantiate the Activity. In the `onCreate` of your Plugin class use:

```
// get a handle on your Application
Application app = getApplication();    
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
app.startActivity(intent);
```

This will start your Activity and call the standard Lifecycle events.

The way I handle continued communication with the running Activity is by using a `Handler` to send a broadcast from your plugin which the Activity picks up in its receiver. In the `onCreate` of your plugin:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Call the Activity");

                Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.CALL_FROM_PLUGIN);
                intent.putExtra("request", <<Any extras you might want to send through>>);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
```

In the Activity I declare the variable:

```
public static final String CALL_FROM_PLUGIN= "CALL_FROM_PLUGIN";
```

then in `onCreate()` I added the following;

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(CALL_FROM_PLUGIN);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

and then implemented a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()");

        if (CALL_FROM_PLUGIN.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received call from Plugin");
            // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
        } 
    }
};
```

Someone else might be able to point out why this is necessary from a framework point of view, but this is the way I understand that Activities should be called. I hope this applies to your plugin class the way it does with my service class!

Comment: thank you very much, a complete Answer. thanks again!